# Core plot CPTTimeFormatter fixed xAxis time interval

Tags: objective-c, core-plot

I am using core plot to plot a graph with the xAxis.labelFormatter being a CPTTimeFormatter. So I have set a reference date, and I have my data plotted nicely along the xAxis. The first xAsis label is "00" (midnight) and the last xAxis label is "00" which is great, working as required to display data over a 24 hour period.

However, I noticed when I change the iPhone simulator time zone to a different timezone, the first xAxis label is "17" and the last is "17". In other words the xAxis has shifted backwards 7 hours. I need the graph to show data from midnight to midnight (for a specific timezone), regardless of where the user is located physically.

The problem is that my plot range is not setting correctly, in the below snippet the 'baseInt' is not the start of the day in the timezone I want..

```
CPTPlotRange *plotRange = [CPTPlotRange      plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(baseInt) length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(60*60*24)];
```

I work out baseInt by:

```
NSTimeInterval baseInt = [[self beginningOfDay:[NSDate date]] timeIntervalSinceDate:[CommonStuff referenceDate]];
```

It's the [NSDate date] that's throwing this out. The [CommonStuff referenceDate] is not changing.

How can I specify a NSTimeInterval from my referenceDate (fixed/not changing) to the *start of the day in a specific timezone*? Perhaps I need to work out the difference between timezones and add that difference in seconds to baseInt?

FYI my beginning of day method is as follows:

```
//return me the date for start of the day
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [cal components:( NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond | NSCalendarUnitDay ) fromDate:date];

[components setHour:0];
[components setMinute:0];
[components setSecond:0];

return [cal dateFromComponents:components];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You answered your own question—you need to account for the timezone difference. One way would be to set the timezone of the `NSCalendar` in the `-beginningOfDay:` method.